# Login page doesnt recognise fields as completed when using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following code to enter my username and password on a website and then login (by sending the enter key)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.firefox()
browser.get('http://www.example.com')

username = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("MyUsername")
password.send_keys("MyPassword")

password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This works as expected however, i run into some trouble when the website validates the fields. Upon pressing enter it returns the message "Username is required" despite the field being completed.

Could this issue relate to the login page using JS or Knockout? If so, im unfamiliar with either of these. Is there a workaround?

Here is the form HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/Pretend_login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <input data-bind="value:email" name="username" type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <input data-bind="value:password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"  data-bind="visible: error_message().length">
        <div>
            <span class="text-danger" data-bind="text: error_message"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <a role="button" href="/Forgotten_password">Forgotten password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you `import time` and add `time.sleep(1)` before `password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`? Issue still persists?

Comment: I have tried this. I even tried adding `time.sleep(5)` between each line of code just to be sure but it still doesn't work.

Comment: And what if to try `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value="MyUsername";', username)` ? and same for password field

Comment: Still isn't recognising the fields as entered. I'm not even sure what the cause of it happening is.

Comment: Share `HTML` for `<form>` block

Comment: Sure. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Looks ok, nothing unusual... Have you tried to use `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()` or `password.submit()` instead of `password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`?

Comment: Still the same. I have also tried getting selenium to fill in the fields and then pressing the submit button manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your page under test but I have struggled with similar issues on a web application that also uses JavaScript to validate user input. The problem was that this validation only triggered when another input field got the focus. So you can basically try a few things here:

1. trigger the **blur** event with JavaScriptExecutor after filling out the field
2. send_keys(Keys.TAB) after filling out the field
3. click on any other input field - this should also trigger the **blur** event

I could only provide Java examples because I have not done anything in Python yet. If this would still be helpful, please let me know.
Java Example for **blur** event:

```
String highlight = "arguments[0].blur()";
((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript(highlight, element);
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with JavaScriptExecutor. How would i go about triggering a blur event using it? Entering Keys.TAB doesn't fix the issue
EDIT: Just realised you said you haven't done python. I will reply if i figure it out.

Comment: I added an example for the JavaScriptExecutor in Java. Hope it helps.